Can't get at light bulbs to replace them
I have just bought a flat, and the lighting is very nice, but a bit too creative for my meagre skills. There are three types of lighting that require bulb replacement, but I can't see how to get the old bulbs out! Here is the big type, 9.5cm across, bathroom-rated:

I can pull it out about 1.5cm by hand, but no further. I'm reluctant to try and force it with a lever, without knowing how it's supposed to  come free. It won't twist at all.
Here is the small type, 3cm across, shower-rated:

I can't get under this at all. Not with a flat-blade screwdriver, not with a butter knife.
And here is the tiny type, 1.5cm across, floor-level lights in the kitchen:

I did manage to prise this off, but what I saw suggested to me that maybe I shouldn't have:

That bulb is not much bigger than a peppercorn. I can't possibly get it out.
I can't get behind any of these without dismantling the walls. Surely nobody would have installed them without leaving a way to change the bulbs? Help!

My guess is that #1 & #2 are both GU-10 style bulbs (probably LED versions, not halogen). You'd need to press on the face of the bulb (not the housing) and try to twist it anti-clockwise.

@brhans: OK, I've tried that -- but the bulbs don't give at all, or twist. I may have to seek professional help :-(

The peppercorn-sized light may be a bi-pin LED. Find a piece of clear PVC tubing that is the right size to slide onto the bulb using some force, then give it a quick pull. When installing a new bulb, barely insert it into the tubing just enough that it won't fall out, then push to seat the pins and gently rock the tubing to remove.

We have some of the first type in our house. They're sealed units, designed for bathrooms, and so the bulbs can't be replaced. The unit is held in with sprung "arms", so you'll need to pull hard to get the unit out.

A lot of these look like LED bulbs. Most often it is the driver circuit, not the LED, that is bad, due to cheap manufacturers. Maybe look for the driver boxes?

So all your life you've lived in a world where the light emitter is the most fragile thing, and they needed frequent replacement. Your grandfather lived in a world where electronics had vacuum tubes, and they needed frequent replacement.  Then one day, solid-state transistors arrived, and they never burn out.  Imagine grandfather's surprise! Well, the same thing happened to lighting and it's your turn to be surprised.  LED emitters never fail unless they fall off their heat sink obviously. However the electronic drivers do fail because Chinese capacitors etc.
